# Vectorize For Loop that Iterates Over Two Arrays

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two numpy arrays (one containing dataframe indices, the other containing floats) and am using a for loop to find the row index of the first value in df which:

1. has an index greater than the t_index; and
2. the value in the Low column is less than or equal to low.

It works but needs to be optimised. Is it possible to vectorize it to speed up its performance?

```
for t_index, low in zip(t_indices, t_lows):

    t_ix = df.loc[t_index:][(df["Low"] <= low)].index[0]
```

I've not included sample data as I don't think it's helpful here however let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) and the matching expected output. An well crafted example is always helpful to understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can broadcast the comparisons using:

```
tmp = np.where(df.index.to_numpy()[:,None]>=t_indices,
               df['Low'].to_numpy()[:,None] <= t_lows,
              -1
              ) == 1
out = np.where(tmp.any(axis=0), tmp.argmax(axis=0), np.nan)
```

However, this will be using O(n²) of memory.

Example:

```
t_indices = np.array([0,2,1,2,0])
t_lows = np.array([0.2,0.13,0.15,0.17,0.02])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Low': [0.1,0.12,0.11,0.17,1]})
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.,  2.,  1.,  2., nan])
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a sample, it's difficult to solve your problem but numpy broadcasting is a solution to improve performance:

Suppose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Low': [0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5]})
t_indices = df.index
t_lows = np.array([0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8])
print(df)

# Output
   Low
0  0.4
1  0.1
2  0.2
3  0.6
4  0.5
```

You can do:

```
arr = df['Low'].values - np.array(t_lows)[:, None]
arr[np.tril_indices_from(arr, k=-1)] = np.inf
msk = arr <= 0
idx = msk.argmax(axis=1)
print(idx)

# Output
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Details about `arr`:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 0.1, -0.2, -0.1,  0.3,  0.2],
       [ inf, -0.6, -0.5, -0.1, -0.2],
       [ inf,  inf, -0.3,  0.1,  0. ],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  0. , -0.1],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -0.3]])

>>> arr <= 0
array([[False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

The question is: what index should be returned when no value is less than "Low"? Because `argmax` will always return something. To avoid this, `argmax` should return something only and only if there is at least one true value:

```
idx = np.where(msk.any(axis=1), msk.argmax(axis=1), None)
```